# How to get around Host Networking limitation for Docker Compose on Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am writing a `docker-compose` stack on Windows to run my two services, A and B, which talk to each other. When running directly from my machine, `localhost` works fine for these services to communicate.

[Host networking isn't supported for Windows](https://context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress), so when using compose my services can talk to each other using the given hostnames (`service-a:2000` and `service-b:2001` instead of `localhost:2000` and `localhost:2001` which would be fine on Linux). This is fine, until...

I want to be able to run services on my machine and docker compose together. Let's say I want to debug service A in my IDE while running service B as normal in compose. `service-b` isn't in a DNS and A will fail to connect.

I see two options:

Given that Service B exposes `port: -2001:2001`...

- Service A can run with alternate app configuration with Service B at `localhost:2001`
- Update my Windows Hosts file with `127.0.0.1 service-b`

These aren't ideal of course, it would be best to not have alternate configuration or changes to the host machine.

Is there another way to get around this in Docker for Windows that I'm not seeing?

Comment: "Locally on your system" and "in connected Docker containers" are two different environments and it's normal to have different host names for the two setups.  Consider a mechanism like environment variables to allow configuring the service differently in the two environments.  ("On two separate hosts" would be a reasonable third setup.)

Comment: Sure, but "how to do it with additional app configuration" isn't the problem here. This setup is trivial on Linux where the same hostname (localhost) is sufficient for both system and container environments. I'm trying to understand if something similar is possible on Windows that I've overlooked in Docker. Otherwise, environment variables would be another reasonable option

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't think this is a good approach, but I think it'll do what you want.

You can create a hostname that'll mean `localhost` when run on your Windows machine, but will mean the docker host when run in a container. I've settled on the name `host.docker.internal` since that's the common name used for the host when running in a container. I'm not sure that I like that you can use that name on your Windows machine. Maybe you can come up with a better name.

Define an alias for localhost in your `hosts` file on Windows by adding

```
127.0.0.1   host.docker.internal
```

to it.

Then add host.docker.internal as an extra_host to your docker-compose file for each service, like this

```
services:
  app1:
    image: myimage
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Now you should be able to reach the other container using `host.docker.internal` as the hostname both when you run it locally and when it's run in a container.